# CSS Card Flip backface background color not visible on first flip

Tags: css, transform, css-animations

I'm trying your standard 3d card flip. However, the background of the backside the "card" is not showing up until I open up developer tools or flip the card again. Here's the Codepen I have for it.

http://codepen.io/Spidy88/pen/HsFjC

I've looked at this simple example and for the most part my code is identical. I tried changing the front face and back face to be absolute sizes but the issue is still occuring.

http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple hours of playing around, all it took was adding an empty  to the div. I should also note that this issue was found and tested only on Google Chrome 33.0.1750.154. Not sure about previous or future versions.